# Typsetting Problem in better-react-mathjax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, mathjax, typesetting

I am using `better-react-mathjax` for equation writing and reading. Basically, I used the `MathJax` in my equation with a question. When it first loads it does not create a problem.

But when I use to filter using React sate it creates the Typesetting problem and the next app is crashed.

How can I fix the problem?

MathJax

```
import React from 'react'
import { MathJax, MathJaxContext } from "better-react-mathjax";

const config = {
    loader: { load: ["input/asciimath"] }
};

export const MathJaxOutput = ({ text }) => {
    return <MathJaxContext config={config} version={3}>
        <MathJax dynamic inline>
            {text}
        </MathJax>
    </MathJaxContext>
}
```

And the error screenshot is

[image]

When mark and course name changed automatically loads the related questions.

```
state = {
        courseName: '',
        selectedTopics: [],
        mark: null,
        questions:[]
   }
```

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.courseName !== prevState.courseName || this.state.selectedTopics !== prevState.selectedTopics || this.state.mark !== prevState.mark) {
            if (this.state.courseName) {
                this.props.getCourseQuestions(this.state.courseName, this.state.selectedTopics, this.state.mark);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output render

```
{
  this.state.questions.map((question, questionIndex) => (
                    <div className='input-question-field-items' key={questionIndex}>
                            <div className='preview-field-item'>
                                <MathJaxOutput text={<p>{question.questionInput.question}</p>} />
                            </div>
                    </div>
}
```

Comment: You aren't showing your state implementation/filter

Comment: Are you using React >= 16.8?

Comment: Here is a Sandbox with your example (slightly simplified) which works well.. I don't know if you're using a too old React version or something but try to provide a small example in a sandbox where your problem shows. [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-example-6-wptik). (also, it's better to wrap the entire app in a `MathJaxContext` instead of supplying one context per text to typeset.

Comment: Also now when I think about it you should REALLY move the `MathJaxContext` to a parent ... Because now you're readding the context several times in every render, presumably causing MathJax to download over and over again simultaneously. Check the docs here: [instruction](https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax#basic-workflow). Put the context higher up in a component which does not get replaced / changed all the time.

Comment: I am using react version 17.

Comment: Try to provide a sandbox with a minimum sample where the problem shows and I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake. You are right. It is basically a problem with render. When is the use componentDidUpdate it can not download MathJax immediately? So the error occurred. Thanks a lot for your good suggestion. Now I used without componentDidUpdate it works fine.

Comment: But can I handle this problem using the componentDidUpdate life cycle method? Like, say when my state change it will automatically fetch data from the server. How can I do this? Please help. I If you need a code demo. I can provide.

Comment: As long as you provide the `MathJaxContext` component higher up in the hierarchy where it remains during the whole lifetime of the app, that shouldn't be a problem. Wrap the entire app in it and don't use it at all elsewhere. If you can't get it to work, supply a sandbox where the problem shows and I'll help you :)